# MediaWiki installed on virtual server accessed through Apache ProxyPass

Tags: wiki, mediawiki, virtualhost, proxypass

> **Note**: where you will see "**xttp**" actualy is "**http**" but stackoverflow rules do not allow me to use more than 1 hyperlink in one post because I do not have enough "credit" to do that :)

## INTRODUCTION

Hi,

I have installed a MediaWiki 1.15.3 software on a private LAN on a Linux box (CentOS 5), with: Apache 2.2.3, PHP 5.1.6, MySQL 5.0.45. Let's name this Linux box "wiki box".

Public users can't access this wiki as it is hosted on a private LAN.

For external users (the Internet users) we have a Linux router (with Apache 2.0.52) where we host our website (ex: xttp://www.cubique.ro).  Let's name this Linux box "router".

## WHAT I WANT

What I want to do is:

1. to create a virtual domain (as xttp://wiki.cubique.ro)  on the "router"
2. setup the virtual domain to forward all xttp requests to my private "wiki box" (ex: xttp://192.168.0.200/wiki_root/)

## WHAT I'VE DONE ALREADY

On router's Apache (httpd.conf) I have created a VirtualHost as:

> < VirtualHost 0.0.0.0:80 >
>   ServerName wiki.cubique.ro
>   DocumentRoot /someinternalpath/html
>   ScriptAlias /cgi-bin /someinternalpath/cgi-bin
>   ...

Well, after I have navigate at wiki.cubique.ro I saw a blank web page, as /someinternalpath/html has an empty index.htm page.

No problem, I know that I have to "teach" the router to pass all the access of virtual domain (wiki.cubique.ro) to the wiki box, where the real pages are stored.

So I teach the Apache to ProxyPass the access of virtual domain root to the wiki box root like this:

> *...the following lines lies in the same virtual domain definition, see above*
>   ProxyPass        / xttp://192.168.0.200/wiki/
>   ProxyPassReverse / xttp://192.168.0.200/wiki/
>   < /VirtualHost >

## WHAT IS THE ISSUE

If I access the wiki using the internal address (such as xttp://192.168.0.200/wiki/) it looks splendid (style sheets, everything).
When I access the wiki using the virtual domain name ( xttp://wiki.cubique.ro ) it shows the content but no style sheet. Worse than that, no internal wiki links are working at all.

Make a try: http://wiki.cubique.ro

## FINALLY, THE QUESTION

Anyone has a clue how to deal with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your path variables in [LocalSettings.php](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:LocalSettings.php), especailly [$wgStylePath](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgStylePath) and [$wgServer](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgServer)

Comment: I will. Thanks for the answer and sorry for late reply.